# Why is viewController's initializer not declared in its interface file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In Xcode 5, when I create a new a XIB and the following set of files are generated

```
mainViewController.h
mainViewController.m
mainViewController.xib
```

`mainViewController.m` defines an initializer method:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

However, this method is not declared in `mainViewController.h`

`AppDelegate.m` calls this initializer. But `AppDelegate.h` only imports `mainViewController.h` and not `mainViewController.m`

How can `AppDelegate.m` call `- (id)initWithNibName` without warning if this method is not declared publicly in the interface file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `initWithNibName` is declared publicly by `UIViewController`, which your `mainViewController` class inherits from.

Comment: This is makes sense, so all header from the super classe's interface is imported I guess, but in this case does `- (id)initWithNibName` overwrites the one in its superclass?

Comment: Yes, an inherited method will overwrite that of its superclass if implemented. That is why they call [super initWithNibName] in the default stub, so both get executed.